# Linear Programming Simplex Method: What exactly are the basic and non-basic variables?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm having a little bit of confusion understanding what exactly are the basic and non-basic variables in a linear programming problem when using the Simplex Method. From my understanding and reading the textbook, basic variables are the variables that we solve for (slack variables), and non-basic variables are the ones that are set to 0 (the objective function P's initial parameters).

However, looking at some other videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2QL4YvSzi0&ab_channel=CatherineSporer at 2:06), it seems that some of the slack variables are actually considered basic variables. Is there a standardized way for determining straight away from a standard LP problem statement, what are the basic and non-basic variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which variables are the basic variables will change over time. In the simplex method, you:

1. Find a *basic* feasible solution: a feasible solution where we set the nonbasic variables to $0$, which lets us uniquely solve for the basic variables.
2. Do a pivot step where we change a nonbasic variable to basic, and then make one of the old basic variables nonbasic. This gives us a different basic feasible solution. If we chose the entering variable correctly, it's a better one.
3. Repeat this, moving from one basic feasible solution to another, until we get to the optimal solution.

What the slack variables give us is a *starting* set of basic variables. The simplex method is helpless if it doesn't have a basic feasible solution to work with. In the special case where our constraints are $Ax \le b, x \ge 0$ with nonnegative $b$, we can find a basic feasible solution easily. First change the constraints to $Ax + Is = b$ with $x,s \ge 0$; then make $s$ basic and $x$ nonbasic.

As we perform the simplex method, the set of basic variables will change. Some slack variables will become nonbasic, and some of the other variables will become basic.

(Also, if we *don't* have an LP in the special form where we can add slack variables, then it is much harder to find an initial basic feasible solution - and it might not even exist. This is where the two-phase simplex method comes in.)